# VBA To Write CSV Format to Text File - 2 Snagging Points

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, vba

Currently trying to generate a text file as CSV format from excel.

The code below does that just fine to my highlighted range. However, I've now discovered that there are two snagging points which make the request slightly different to a standard CSV text file.

Is it possible to enclose numbers in double quotes and also any non-populated fields?

eg. desired result:

"Test","","1","2","3"

Rather than:

"Test",,1,2,3

Current VBA below. I'm not sure a change to this will necessarily be the answer but I'm truly stuck.

```
Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\test.txt"
Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
Write #1, cellValue
Else
Write #1, cellValue,

End If

Next j
Next i

Close #1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, """" & cellValue & """"
Else
    Write #1, """" & cellValue & """",
End If
```

if the text cells are somehow already getting the double quotes and you don't want to get ""text"" then you may need to check to see if they are null or a number.

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    if IsEmpty(cellValue) = true or isnumeric(cellValue) = true then
        Write #1, """" & cellValue & """"
    else
        Write #1,cellValue
    End if
Else
    if IsEmpty(cellValue) = true or isnumeric(cellValue) = true then
        Write #1, """" & cellValue & """", 
    else
        Write #1, cellValue, 
    End if
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

MatthewD, brilliant.

I changed:

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
Write #1, """" & cellValue & """"
Else
Write #1, """" & cellValue & """",
End If
```

to:

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
Write #1, "" & cellValue & ""
Else
Write #1, "" & cellValue & "",
End If
```

and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help and pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Glad to help you out. Sometimes it is two double quotes to get a single and sometimes it is four. I think it depends on what your doing with it.